# SQL query for extracting year from a date

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, peoplesoft

I am trying to create a query that gets only the year from selected dates. I.e. `select ASOFDATE from PSASOFDATE;` returns `11/15/2012`, but I want only `2012`. How can I get only the year? I know the `YEAR` function can be used, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The question was retagged from [tag:mysql] to [tag:oracle]. This introduced quite a bit of confusion in this Q&A. Knowing this, the answers are a lot less surprising.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Comment: @Palec If I recall right... at that time, there was also a confirmation OP being a puppet account...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: due to post-tag 'oracle', the first two queries become irrelevant, leaving 3rd query for oracle.

For MySQL:

```
SELECT YEAR(ASOFDATE) FROM PASOFDATE
```

Editted:
In anycase if your date is a String, let's convert it into a proper date format. And select the year out of it.

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(ASOFDATE, '%d-%b-%Y')) FROM PSASOFDATE
```

Since you are trying Toad, can you check the following code:

For Oracle:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (TO_DATE(YEAR, 'MM/DD/YY') FROM ASOFDATE) FROM PSASOFDATE;
```

[Reference:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)

Comment: For you to get a better understanding on [date, time related manupulations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), please take a look at this link as well. Hope that helps in the long run :)

Comment: That's because i misspelled your table name I guess... can you try the `DATE(date column)` and your proper column name and table name :)

Comment: what would the query look like exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I got disconnected. It seems you have voted for John Woo's answer. So did it work for you? Frankly, it's important to dig into the issue you are getting. I am more curious to know if you are still getting the error if not which answer solved that issue and got you the correct results.

Comment: I didn't vote for anyones.  Im pretty sure all of your answers are correct, but I don't know why it won't work.  I'm using Peoplesoft and Toad as the SQL interface...

Comment: I was referring to votes, coz I had the impression his answers solved your issue. Anyway, you may want to use `CAST` and `EXTRACT` if it's TOAD. [CAST, EXTRACT](http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/KnowledgeXpertforOracle/tabid/648/TopicID/CAEF/Default.aspx)

Comment: What would the query look like using CAST?

Comment: Did you try the above extract code? I have updated to convert the string to Date and then use EXTRACT to get the year out. And if it works please let us know.

Comment: I am glad. So you do not actually need CAST to be used. However I have updated the answer to convert your date into DATE. That also says you are using TOAD SQL which is more of the Oracle PL/SQL decendent type. Not MYSQL :) The invalid identifier was due to the fact we used wrong language keywords/syntaxes in your TOAD query.

Comment: The first two queries are for MySQL, the third one is for Oracle. Since the question is tagged [tag:oracle], this is fairly misleading and should be explicitly stated in the question.

Answer (score 51):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ASOFDATE) FROM PSASOFDATE;
```

Answer (score 26):

How about this one?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ASOFDATE, 'YYYY') FROM PSASOFDATE
```

Comment: it return a string not a number, bad idea

Comment: @Juan I agree with you Juan. Good answer. Totally OK to use a string when you consistently use a 4 digit year.  If you add the day and/or month and you want to SORT, sort by the date column itself or by a to_char string with the 'YYYY/MM/DD' or similar format to get the correct order.

Answer (score 4):

just pass the columnName as parameter of `YEAR`

```
SELECT YEAR(ASOFDATE) from PSASOFDATE;
```

another is to use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ASOFDATE, '%Y') from PSASOFDATE;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3899)

**UPDATE 1**

I bet the value is varchar with the format MM/dd/YYYY, it that's the case,

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('11/15/2012', '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3908)

**LAST RESORT if all the queries fail**

use `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('11/15/2012', 7, 4)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3909)

Comment: how about the second one using `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: what is the data type of `ASOFDATE`? and how is the value formatted?

Comment: it displayed the same error for the second query.  I am not sure what the data type is..let me try to pull it up..

Comment: @StackOver I updated the answer, see the result of the fiddle.

Comment: @StackOver see my updated answer, the format of your date is `M/d/Y` right? try converting it back to date.

Comment: This answer is MySQL only. After the retag to [tag:oracle], this one is completely invalid. I suggest adding a warning to the top of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT date_column_name FROM table_name WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_column_name) = 2020`